# Matching rows to columns and counting same occurences R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

I have a dataset which is of the following form:-

```
a <- data.frame(X1=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                X2=c("B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B"),
                X3=c("B", "E", "A", "A", "A", "B"),
                X4=c("E", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C"),
                X5=c("A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B")
               )
```

And I have another set of the following form:-

```
b <- data.frame(col_1=c("ASD", "ASD", "BSD", "BSD"),
                col_2=c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                col_3=c(12, 12, 31, 21),
                col_4=("A", "B", "B", "A")
               )
```

What I want to do is to take the column `col_4` from set `b` and match row wise in set `a`, so that it tell me which row has how many elements from `col_4` in a new column. The name of the new column does not matters.

For ex:- The first and fifth row in set `a` has all the elements of `col_4` from set `b`.

Also, duplicates shouldn't be found. For ex.  sixth row in set `a` has 3 `"B"`s. But since `col_4` from set `b` has only two `"B"`s, it should tell me 2 and not 3.

Expected output is of the form:-

```
c <- data.frame(X1=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                X2=c("B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B"),
                X3=c("B", "E", "A", "A", "A", "B"),
                X4=c("E", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C"),
                X5=c("A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B"),
                found=c(4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2)
               )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `vecsets::vintersect` which takes care of duplicates.

Using `apply` row-wise we can count how many common values are there between `b$col4` and each row in `a`.

```
apply(a, 1, function(x) length(vecsets::vintersect(b$col_4, x)))
#[1] 4 1 2 2 4 2
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

#convert a into a long format
m <- melt(setDT(a)[, rn:=.I], id.vars="rn", value.name="col_4")

#order by row number and create an index for identical occurrences in col_4
setorder(m, rn, col_4)[, vidx := rowid(col_4), rn]

#create a similar index for b
setDT(b, key="col_4")[, vidx := rowid(col_4)]

#count occurrences and lookup this count into original data
a[b[m, on=.(col_4, vidx), nomatch=0L][, .N, rn], on=.(rn), found := N]
```

output:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 rn found
1:  A  B  B  E  A  1     4
2:  B  C  E  C  C  2     1
3:  C  C  A  A  C  3     2
4:  A  A  A  A  A  4     2
5:  B  A  A  A  B  5     4
6:  C  B  B  C  B  6     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea to operate on sets efficiently is to *count* and compare the element *occurences* of `b$col_4` in each row of `a`:

```
b1 = c(table(b$col_4))
#b1
#A B 
#2 2

a1 = table(factor(as.matrix(a), names(b1)), row(a))
#a1
#   
#    1 2 3 4 5 6
#  A 2 0 2 5 3 0
#  B 2 1 0 0 2 3
```

Finally, identify the least amount of occurences per element (for each row) and sum:

```
colSums(pmin(a1, b1))
#1 2 3 4 5 6 
#4 1 2 2 4 2
```

In case of a larger dimension `a` "data.frame" and more elements, `Matrix::sparseMatrix` offers an appropriate alternative:

```
library(Matrix)

a.fac = factor(as.matrix(a), names(b1))
.i = as.integer(a.fac)
.j = c(row(a))

noNA = !is.na(.i)  ## need to remove NAs manually
.i = .i[noNA]
.j = .j[noNA]

a1 = sparseMatrix(i = .i, j = .j, x = 1L, dimnames = list(names(b1), 1:nrow(a)))

a1
#2 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#  1 2 3 4 5 6
#A 2 . 2 5 3 .
#B 2 1 . . 2 3

colSums(pmin(a1, b1))
#1 2 3 4 5 6 
#4 1 2 2 4 2
```